# How to properly destroy Mongoid embedded object with relations?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I made test script to demonstrate my problem.

```ruby
    require 'mongoid' 
    
    ## mongoid.yml
    # development:
    #   clients:
    #     default:
    #       database: test
    #       hosts:
    #         - localhost:27017
    Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :development)
    
    class Foo
      include Mongoid::Document
      embeds_one :bar
    end
    
    class Bar
      include Mongoid::Document
      embedded_in :any
      has_many :bazs, as: :barable
    end
    
    class Baz
      include Mongoid::Document
      belongs_to :barable, polymorphic: true
    end
    
    foo = Foo.create(
      bar: Bar.new(
        bazs: [Baz.create]
      )
    )
    
    foo.bar.destroy
```

I need to destroy `bar` object with all `bazs`.

When I try to destroy embedded Bar object I get an error `undefined method barable` for `Foo` instance. But `Bar` doesn't relate to `Foo` as `barable`. Also I tryied use `delete` instead `destroy`.

How can I delete `bar` with all `bazs`?

```
$ ruby test3.rb 
/home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/traversable.rb:109:in `remove_child': undefined method `barable' for #<Foo _id: 60978efab4da6149b72c4bb1, > (NoMethodError)
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/deletable.rb:78:in `delete_as_embedded'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/deletable.rb:33:in `block in delete'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/deletable.rb:131:in `prepare_delete'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/deletable.rb:23:in `delete'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/destroyable.rb:32:in `block in destroy'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:143:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/destroyable.rb:32:in `destroy'
    from /home/vp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongoid-5.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:150:in `method_missing'
    from test3.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot target an embedded class with referenced associations, because an embedded document cannot be found by its id alone (you need the ids of the each document in the composition hierarchy all the way to the top level).